# How to use system environment variables instead configuration.properties in automation framework?

Tags: java, maven, automation, testng, teamcity

I have created a WebApp test automation framework for my project on my local machine using Maven, Java and TestNG frameworks. We have TeamCity in our CI/CD and my team would like the framework to use TeamCity's environment variables (including username and pass to the WebApp under test) instead porperties hard coded in my projects 'configuration.properties' file.

The mechanism used in my project when it comes to properties configuration is as follows:
- resources package which contains 'configuration.properties' file. This file contains variables such as app.url, browser, chrome.driver.location.
- 'configuration.properties' file is then read by classes in configuration package. Classes are as follows: `AppProperties.java`, `ConfigurationProperties.java`, `PropertiesLoader.java`, `LocalWebDriverPorperties.java` and `TestRunProperties .java` classes

**Configuration.properties**

```
app.url=url for app under test
is.remote.run=false
grid.url="";

browser=CHROME
chrome.driver.location=C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe
firefox.driver.location=C:/Selenium/geckodriver.exe
```

**AppProperties.java**

```
package configuration;

public class AppProperties {

        public static String getAllUrl() {
            return ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("app.url");
        }

    }
```

**ConfigurationProperties.java**

```
package configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ConfigurationProperties {

    private static Properties properties;

    private ConfigurationProperties() {
    }


    public static void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        ConfigurationProperties.properties = properties;
    }

    public static Properties getProperties() {
        if (properties == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Please set properties using setProperties() before calling getProperties()");
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**PropertiesLoader.java**

```
package configuration;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesLoader {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PropertiesLoader.class);


    public Properties getPropertiesFromFile(String propertiesFileName) {


        InputStream inputStream = null;


        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            logger.info("Trying to load properties with file name: " + propertiesFileName);


            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);


            if (inputStream != null) {

                properties.load(inputStream);
                logger.info("Successfully loaded properties for file: " + propertiesFileName);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Property file '" + propertiesFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load properties due to IOException!");
        } finally {

            closeResource(inputStream);
        }


        return properties;
    }

    private void closeResource(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**LocalWebDriverProperties.java**

```
package configuration;

public class LocalWebDriverProperties {

       return BrowserType.valueOf(ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("browser"));
//    }
    public static String getChromeWebDriverLocation() {
        return ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("chrome.driver.location");
    }

    public static String getFirefoxWebDriverLocation() {
        return ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("firefox.driver.location");
    }

    public static String getInternetExplorerWebDriverLocation() {
        return ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("ie.driver.location");
    }
}
```

**TestRunProperties.java**

```
package configuration;
import driver.manager.BrowserType;


public class TestRunProperties {

    public static String getGridUrl() {
        return ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("grid.url");
    }

    public static BrowserType getBrowserToRun() {
        return BrowserType.valueOf(ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("browser"));
    }

    public static boolean getIsRemoteRun(){
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(ConfigurationProperties.getProperties().getProperty("is.remote.run"));
    }
}
```

The above configuration works fine if i specify server properties like (app.url, browser) used by Team City server in configuration.properties file of the framework. 
But what i am looking for is to use a different approach and instead of having properties set up in configuration.properties file- use an environment variables of TeamCity.

Probably having this functionality in one class like `AppProperties.java` instead of using 5 classes as I am doing at the moment.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps mimic Spring, which has a hierarchy to determine app configuration.  In your case, if an environment variable exists then use it, else use an attribute from a config file.  See also: [12 Factor App - item III](https://12factor.net/config).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, i found that it is possible to alter POM.xml in my Maven project to create profiles and use given system's environment variables within created profiles. You can then trigger this by running mvn -P in cmd line. I will give it a go:)